# CommonsChunkPlugin and multiple common bundles

Tags: webpack

The question is maybe a little misleading, but I’ll try to understand with the example.

---

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor1: [
            'module1'
        ],
        vendor2: [
            'module2'
        ]
        index1: 'index1.js',
        index2: 'index2.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['vendor2', 'vendor1'],
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ]
};
```

Following configuration will create shared bundles `vendor1` and `vendor2` collecting all same chunks from entry points.

What I want to achieve is following: have another vendor bundle, `vendor3`, which has `module1`, `module2` and `module3` but doesn’t share it with `vendor1` and `vendor2` bundle - it should act like standalone commons chunk output target. It should behave something in the lines of the following configuration, but be inside same compiling process:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor3: [
            'module1',
            'module2',
            'module3'
        ],
        index1: 'index1.js',
        index2: 'index2.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['vendor3'],
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ]
};
```

Can this be achieved? Is this maybe achieveable with multi compiler support? I hope that my question is understandable!